# My comments got stretched across the screen, and it won't allow me to edit or delete the comment either.

Tags: support, bug, mathjax, comment

I must have added something in MathJax that caused my comment and subsequently caused previous comments to stretch across the page.  I tried to hit "edit" or just delete the last comment but it doesn't work either.  I've flagged my own question for moderator attention, but by any chance does anyone know how I can fix this myself (I know the moderators probably have lots of flags to get to...)

Here is the question link:

[Show that if some equation is solvable modulo $p$, then it is also solvable modulo $p^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923482/show-that-if-some-equation-is-solvable-modulo-p-then-it-is-also-solvable-modu)

Thanks,

Comment: I do not see the offending comment. (Maybe it renders differently for me, maybe mods already corrected it.) Anyway, some suggestions how to deal with this without moderator's intervention [are listed here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/workaround-for-broken-comments). (I should probably add that while moderators can *edit* the comment, the only think you can do - even with using the above workarounds - is to delete it. So it the comment contains some relevant reputation, you might try to note it somewhere, so that it is not lost.)

Comment: Hi @MartinSleziak, did you click on the option to "see 6 more comments?"  then it shows ...

Comment: Yep, I've tried deleting it - doesn't work @MartinSleziak :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several suggestions how to deal with this without moderator's intervention are listed here: [Workaround for broken comments](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/workaround-for-broken-comments). (I should probably add that while moderators can edit the comment, the only think you can do - even with using the above workarounds - is to delete it. So it the comment contains some relevant reputation, you might try to note it somewhere, so that it is not lost.)

To be more specific, the approach using scaling math size is suggested in [Willie Wong's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long/2818#2818). And [Asaf Karagila's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/formatting-bug-long-mathjax-or-code-blocks-break-entire-post-or-page/13604#13604) suggests using developer tools. In his [comments here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23698/comment-spreaded-all-over-the-webpage-unable-to-edit-unable-to-delete#comment95362_23698) Asaf also explains how to delete the sidebar.

---

One additional suggestion from me: Try to change Math Renderer in MathJax settings. (A screenshot showing how to do this can be found, for example, [here](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/667/slow-editing-in-new-website/669#669). It is probably easier if you right click on MathJax code that works rather than on the problematic part.) Even if some renderers still have this problem, choosing Plain Source as Math Renderer should help you to be able to delete the comment. (As pointed out in [Davide Cervone's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24987/my-comments-got-stretched-across-the-screen-and-it-wont-allow-me-to-edit-or-de/24988?noredirect=1#comment97854_24988).)

This is how [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923482/show-that-if-some-equation-is-solvable-modulo-p-then-it-is-also-solvable-modu#comment3950860_1923482) looks for me with SVG:

[image]

This is how it looks with HTML-CSS:

[image]

Since in the first case the comment is not stretched wide, I guess to the author of the comment also the delete-comment button is shown.

Comment: +1 My view with the Common HTML renderer is quite similar to your SVG rendered results.

Comment: Switching to Plain Source output also should allow the output to not extend outside the comment area.